# Как изменить пословицу "Тише едешь — дальше будешь"?

Tags: значение-слов, фразеология, пословицы

**Пословицы** обычно используются с определенным значением и в определенной форме, хотя существуют **варианты** с другой записью и даже другим смыслом.

Вот известная пословица: ***Тише едешь — дальше будешь***.

Какое количество **вариантов** вам известно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сколько вариантов знаю – не знаю.
Если самому трудно подсчитать, можно списать у других. Без сортировки:

*Шибко ехать – не скоро доехать.

Езди потиху – избудешь лихо.

Поспешишь – людей насмешишь.

Скоро пойдёшь, так ногу зашибёшь.

Что скоро, то не споро.

Прытко бегают, так часто падают.

Торопиться жить – скоро умереть.

За дурной головой ногам работа.

Спеши, да не торопись.

Торопись медленно.

Поспешай медленно, не торопясь.

Прежде чем что-то делать, семь раз подумай.

Медленно дуб вырастает.

Внутреннее спокойствие ведёт далеко.

Чем больше поспешности, тем хуже удаётся.

Спешащего медленный догоняет.

Кто едет тише, едет скорее.

Если спешишь, то сядь.

Спешащие позднее оканчивают.

В промысле спешка – что без глаз слежка.

Короткий путь приводит к длинным задержкам.

Лучше меньше да лучше.

Семь раз отмерь, один раз отрежь.

Лучше подстраховаться, чем потом переделывать.

Не лезь поперёд батьки в пекло.

Курочка по зёрнышку клюёт.

Торопливость хороша при ловле блох.

Москва не сразу строилась.

Скоро сказка сказывается, да не скоро дело делается.

Тихая вода берега подмывает.

Лучше низом, нежели горою.*

От себя: *Спешка делу не товарищ.*

Ну, пока хватит, потому что...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто! А где списали?  Пословицу сами сочинили?  И картинка хороша!

Comment: Спасибо! С инета, вестимо. От себя – ну да. А картинку эту давно увидел, очень повеселила, сохранил.

Answer (score 2):

Варианты: *Тише едешь — едешь дальше*; *Тише будешь — будешь дальше*; *Будешь? — едешь дальше*; *Едешь? — тише!* Реплики: *Дальше тише будешь*; *Едешь дальше... Тише, тише!*

(Нельзя не вспомнить классическую из КВН 60-х гг.: *Тише будешь — дальше едешь*).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня.  Даже не задумывалась над такими вариантами.  Форм много, но сколько смысловых значений? (1) Не торопись, будь аккуратен,  а то в аварию попадешь. (2) Не задирайся, веди себя тише.   Так быстрее доедешь, а то  можно остановиться или обратно повернуть.  Я все назвала?

Comment: «Будешь ли» имеет «синоним»: *за компанию — по соточке?*. Предложение, от которого нельзя отказаться.

Answer (score 2):

Что можно сказать **о русских пословицах?**  Много чего можно, но мне показалась интересной такая мысль: ***мудрость** по-разному отражается **в зеркале** жизни.*

Не секрет, что многие пословицы имеют забытое **продолжение**, например: *Всяк правды ищет, да не всяк ее творит. Дело мастера боится, а иной мастер — дела.  Первый парень на деревне, а деревня в два двора.*

Но есть пословицы **с вновь приобретенным продолжением**, например: *Яблоко от яблони недалеко падает, но далеко катится. Семь бед — один ответ, восьмая беда — совсем никуда.*

Материал взят  **[из статьи](https://adme.media/svoboda-kultura/35-izvestnyh-poslovic-u-kotoryh-okazyvaetsya-est-prodolzhenie-i-poroj-ono-polnostyu-menyaet-ih-smysl-1940665/)**

**Современное творчество** особенно интересно.  Вот и для нашей пословицы попался мне любопытный вариант. Что в нем удивительного?

(1) Эта тема еще **не раскрыта**  в предложенных вариантах.

(2) В пословице надо **изменить** всего одну букву. **А какую?**

Comment: Я тоже видел "забытые продолжения": *Тише едешь – дальше будешь **от того места, куда едешь***. Но не стал говорить об этом, так как пишут, что это просто шутливая прибавка. Даже если и было так, то нынешний вариант приобрёл своё устоявшееся значение. //  Букву изменить, наверно, так: *Тише едешь – д**о**льше будешь*.  А ещё так: *Тише едешь – **ж**альше будешь.* :))

Comment: Угадали! Тише едешь – дОльше будешь. (Тоже из Емца.) И второй вариант хорош: жальше будешь. Как вы все это придумываете?  Мой respect!!  Цитата: Девиз папы: «Тише едешь – дóльше будешь». Папа занудливо осторожен. На светофоре ещё зелёный, а он уже заранее остановился. В ванной стиральную машинку надо включить – он в резиновых тапках встаёт на резиновый коврик.